# How to get data from mongoDB like a HashMap(Key value Pair)

Tags: mongodb, hashmap, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here are the records in my mongodb

```
{
    "_id": "5a65a047992e3c2572f74102",
    "_class": "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "address": "Purna to Loha Rd, Maharashtra 431511, India",
        "device_id": 23613,
        "last_updated": "2018-01-22T08:26:47.237Z"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "_class": "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
        "coordinates": [77.065659, 19.145168],
        "type": "Point"
    }
},

{
    "_id": "5a65ae1e992e3c2572f74114",
    "_class": "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "address": "Taranagar - Churu Rd, Chalkoi Baneerotan, Rajasthan 331001, India",
        "device_id": 23658,
        "last_updated": "2018-01-22T09:25:50.893Z"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "_class": "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
        "coordinates": [74.956284, 28.497661],
        "type": "Point"
    }
}
```

I want to get it as a key value pair: 
 **key should be "properties.device_id" and value  entire record**.

Like this

```
[23613] => {
    "_id": "5a65a047992e3c2572f74102",
    "_class": "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "address": "Purna to Loha Rd, Maharashtra 431511, India",
        "device_id": 23613,
        "last_updated": "2018-01-22T08:26:47.237Z"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "_class": "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
        "coordinates": [77.065659, 19.145168],
        "type": "Point"
    }
}

[23658] => {
    "_id": "5a65ae1e992e3c2572f74114",
    "_class": "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "address": "Taranagar - Churu Rd, Chalkoi Baneerotan, Rajasthan 331001, India",
        "device_id": 23658,
        "last_updated": "2018-01-22T09:25:50.893Z"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "_class": "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
        "coordinates": [74.956284, 28.497661],
        "type": "Point"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get a result like this without iterating through records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)** pipeline stage to create a new field say `root` that is an array of a document that contains two fields, `k` and `v` where:

```
The k field contains the field name.
The v field contains the value of the field.
```

In your case `k` should be the `device_id` field. Since this is a double type, you need a hack to convert it to a string for later. So your initial pipeline looks as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "root": [
                {
                    "k": { "$substr": [ "$properties.device_id", 0, -1 ] },
                    "v": "$$ROOT"
                }
            ]                
        }
    }
])
```

which will return the following documents

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "5a65a047992e3c2572f74102",
    "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "address" : "Purna to Loha Rd, Maharashtra 431511, India",
        "device_id" : 23613.0,
        "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T08:26:47.237Z"
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            77.065659, 
            19.145168
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "root" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "23613",
            "v" : {
                "_id" : "5a65a047992e3c2572f74102",
                "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
                "type" : "Feature",
                "properties" : {
                    "address" : "Purna to Loha Rd, Maharashtra 431511, India",
                    "device_id" : 23613.0,
                    "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T08:26:47.237Z"
                },
                "geometry" : {
                    "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
                    "coordinates" : [ 
                        77.065659, 
                        19.145168
                    ],
                    "type" : "Point"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5a65ae1e992e3c2572f74114",
    "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "address" : "Taranagar - Churu Rd, Chalkoi Baneerotan, Rajasthan 331001, India",
        "device_id" : 23658.0,
        "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T09:25:50.893Z"
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            74.956284, 
            28.497661
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "root" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "23658",
            "v" : {
                "_id" : "5a65ae1e992e3c2572f74114",
                "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
                "type" : "Feature",
                "properties" : {
                    "address" : "Taranagar - Churu Rd, Chalkoi Baneerotan, Rajasthan 331001, India",
                    "device_id" : 23658.0,
                    "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T09:25:50.893Z"
                },
                "geometry" : {
                    "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
                    "coordinates" : [ 
                        74.956284, 
                        28.497661
                    ],
                    "type" : "Point"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

From here you would want to leverage the **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** operator so that you convert the newly added root to an object with `device_id` as the key:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "root": [
                {
                    "k": { "$substr": [ "$properties.device_id", 0, -1 ] },
                    "v": "$$ROOT"
                }
            ]                
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "root": {
                "$arrayToObject": "$root"
            }             
        }
    }
])
```

which outputs:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "5a65a047992e3c2572f74102",
    "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "address" : "Purna to Loha Rd, Maharashtra 431511, India",
        "device_id" : 23613.0,
        "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T08:26:47.237Z"
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            77.065659, 
            19.145168
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "root" : {
        "23613" : {
            "_id" : "5a65a047992e3c2572f74102",
            "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
            "type" : "Feature",
            "properties" : {
                "address" : "Purna to Loha Rd, Maharashtra 431511, India",
                "device_id" : 23613.0,
                "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T08:26:47.237Z"
            },
            "geometry" : {
                "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    77.065659, 
                    19.145168
                ],
                "type" : "Point"
            }
        }
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5a65ae1e992e3c2572f74114",
    "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "address" : "Taranagar - Churu Rd, Chalkoi Baneerotan, Rajasthan 331001, India",
        "device_id" : 23658.0,
        "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T09:25:50.893Z"
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            74.956284, 
            28.497661
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "root" : {
        "23658" : {
            "_id" : "5a65ae1e992e3c2572f74114",
            "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
            "type" : "Feature",
            "properties" : {
                "address" : "Taranagar - Churu Rd, Chalkoi Baneerotan, Rajasthan 331001, India",
                "device_id" : 23658.0,
                "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T09:25:50.893Z"
            },
            "geometry" : {
                "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    74.956284, 
                    28.497661
                ],
                "type" : "Point"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The last step in the pipeline would be to use [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) pipeline operator to get your desired output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "root": [
                {
                    "k": { "$substr": [ "$properties.device_id", 0, -1 ] },
                    "v": "$$ROOT"
                }
            ]                
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "root": {
                "$arrayToObject": "$root"
            }             
        }
    },
    { "$replaceRoot" : { "newRoot": "$root" } }    
])
```

**Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "23613" : {
        "_id" : "5a65a047992e3c2572f74102",
        "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
        "type" : "Feature",
        "properties" : {
            "address" : "Purna to Loha Rd, Maharashtra 431511, India",
            "device_id" : 23613.0,
            "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T08:26:47.237Z"
        },
        "geometry" : {
            "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                77.065659, 
                19.145168
            ],
            "type" : "Point"
        }
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "23658" : {
        "_id" : "5a65ae1e992e3c2572f74114",
        "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.LocationModel",
        "type" : "Feature",
        "properties" : {
            "address" : "Taranagar - Churu Rd, Chalkoi Baneerotan, Rajasthan 331001, India",
            "device_id" : 23658.0,
            "last_updated" : "2018-01-22T09:25:50.893Z"
        },
        "geometry" : {
            "_class" : "com.vuelogix.location.model.geojson.geometry.Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                74.956284, 
                28.497661
            ],
            "type" : "Point"
        }
    }
}
```